# Redirect only simulation output of vivado tcl command launch_simulation

Tags: tcl, verilog, vivado

I have a verilog testbench with lots of `$display` and `$monitor` commands. I am running the simulation on the tcl command line using `launch_simulation` command.

The command generates a lot of info and status of compilation, elaboration etc in addition to the simulation output. So using the generic `>` to redirect output to file also writes the compilation and elaboration logs also to file.

Is there any way to write just the testbench outputs to file (when using `launch_simulation` with vivado in tcl mode)?

Comment: Are the outputs interleaved? Are they being generated by separate processes? What OS is this running on (POSIX platforms have some more tricks available than Windows)?

Comment: @DonalFellows I am using Windows, the outputs are not exactly interleaved, the log file when redirected using `>` shows: tool log (compile etc), test bench output (desired part) then again some logs

Comment: Prepend a unique string to the $display statements, then grep for that string in the log file. $display("ABCD <whatever you want to print>",<args>) then grep ABCD <log file>.   If you don't have grep on Windows, then write your own filter style program in Python, Perl etc to filer the log file, or download something that will provide the same behavior on Win.  If interleaving the processes is an issue, then give each process a unique identifier string,  process1 is ABCD, process 2 is BCDE.... and use multiple filters/greps to recover the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try using separate Tcl commands to do the compilation and to run the simulation. E.g.:

```
launch_simulation -step compile
launch_simulation -step elaborate
launch_simulation -step simulate > output.txt
```

Or this:

```
set_property -name xsim.simulate.runtime -value 0 -objects [get_filesets sim_1]
launch_simulation
run 1ms > output.txt
```